# Hibernate: the session factory does not read the entity mapping from hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven, jndi

This is my hibernate.cfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <!-- Connessione al database -->         
     <property name="connection.driver_class">
     oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
     </property>
     <property name="connection.url">
     jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
     </property>

    <!-- Credenziali -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">Test</property>
    <property name="connection.password">Test</property>
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">
    org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

    <!--  DISABILITA AUTO COMMIT -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">
    org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

    <!-- Entity -->
    <mapping class= "it.test.Tbl1"></mapping>
    <mapping class= "it.test.Tbl2"></mapping>
    <mapping class= "it.test.Tbl3"></mapping>
    <mapping class= "it.test.Tbl4"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and this the hibernate util file:

When i try to execute a simple query, i got the exception as -> "query exception: table not mapped". 
But if i change the hibernate util as follows,

```
public class HibernateUtil {

        private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

        private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            if (sessionFactory == null)
                sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

the program works with success. 
Why the session factory doesn't gets loaded through configuration file?

console log:

```
10:54:44.989 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounte-    
throwQueryException() : no errors
10:54:45.130 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin  
[level=1, statement=select]

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Tbl1 is not mapped 
[from Tbl1 eat where eat.activityId  = :id]
at  
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException
(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
at  org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString
(QueryException.java:103)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile
(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
```

i think that the problem is this :

```
17:14:47.130 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry -
Registering SessionFactory: a0044811-5a9f-483a-8ede-b136c9781bb3 
(<unnamed>)
17:14:47.130 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - 
Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
17:14:47.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator 
- Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
```

can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

While using method `addAnnotatedClass` you incoded `Tbl1, Tbl2, Tbl3 (2 times)` as mentioned in the code which is just edited and removed. `.addAnnotatedClass(Tbl1.class).addAnnotatedClass(Tbl2.class).addAnnotatedClass(Tbl3.class).addAnnotatedClass(Tbl3.class)`.

While using `xml` configuration you are saying that you have four annotated classes. As mentioned

```
<mapping class= "it.test.Tbl1"></mapping>
<mapping class= "it.test.Tbl2"></mapping>
<mapping class= "it.test.Tbl3"></mapping>
<mapping class= "it.test.Tbl4"></mapping>
```

Please check if mapping for `Tbl4.class` exists or not or try to modify last `addAnnotatedClass(Tbl3.class)` to `.addAnnotatedClass(Tbl4.class)`.

Comment: the program works well if i add the:"sessionFactory = configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Tbl1.class).addAnnotatedClass(Tbl2.class).addAnnotatedClass(Tbl3.class).addAnnotatedClass(Tbl4.class).buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);"
but i wish that the session factory reads the mapping class from the hibernate.cfg.xml. i think that the paser not reads tag mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: In place of `hibernate.connection.username` try `connection.username`.

Comment: Also in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file their is no closing tag `</hibernate-configuration>`

Comment: Are you getting same exception?

Comment: Could you please post your stack trace of exception.

Comment: Could you please write query you are using. And you have written only `query exception: table not mapped` for exception please post your stack trace by printing the exception message.

Comment: Please write your query in comments.

Comment: Query query = session.createQuery("from Tbl1 eat where eat.activityId = :id");
query.setParameter("id", id);

Comment: Are you sure your package structure mention in `hibernate.cfg.xml` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing .hbm files in case of loading via configuration file(xml file). Try adding hbm files for each table.

Comment: the file hbm is necessary also if i use the annotations (@Entity, @Column, etc. )?

Comment: No, it is necessary in case of xml file configuration only. In case of annotaions, the classes in java and tables in db are mapped using @Entity annotations.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. i mean if your cfg file name is different from `hibernate.cfg.xml`, then need to configure `Configuration configuration = new Configuration();            configuration.configure("filename.cfg.xml");` .beacause hibernate by default takes hibernate.cfg.xml file without configuring in `configuration.configure();` but if cfg file name is different then need to put it in configure(). your file need to place in `src` folder. if you place it in different place then need to pass it with correct path.

Comment: no, the file hibernate.cfg.xml is found, because the properties for connection are read, but it is ignored  the tag <mapping class=....\>